# VS Code + Python -> Erros in Pool.Apply_async are ignored?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Take a look at this code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def myFunc():
    nonExistingObject.DoSomething()

def collectFunc():
    pass

#uncomment me for desired behaviour
#myFunc()

pool = mp.Pool(2)
pool.apply_async(myFunc, args=(), callback=collectFunc)
```

If you run it on VS Code, the code completes and no errors are reported, but of course there's an error going on. Not only `nonExistingObject` is not defined but `DoSomething()` also isn't.

If you uncomment the indicated code, you will get the expected error @ runtime. On VSCode I already checked the "Uncaught Exceptions" breakpoints

Is there a way to make the error get caught? is this a python thing or a VSCode thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is quitting before the pool manages to run anything.

Try

```
with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
   pool.apply_async(myFunc, args=(), callback=collectFunc)
```